# Can I get a notification when power state changes while computer is asleep?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, power-management

I'm writing a Windows service application and I'm curious if there's a way to receive a notification when power switches from AC to DC (or vice versa) when the system is in the sleep state?

Comment: I think that this is contradictory by principle. As far as i know as long as a system is sleeping all processes (besides the power manager) are suspended, and no events are sent to processes. How should you receive on? Thats like talking to somebody who is deeply asleep.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR: Yes, obviously the system needs to wake up from sleep first. So you're saying that what I want here is not possible, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegisterSuspendResumeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj613321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  And quite possibly many of the other APIs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm... Thanks. Can you show how exactly am I supposed to use these APIs for my purpose?

Comment: @c00000fd Please be more specific with your question. What part of the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm looking for `a way to receive a notification when power switches from AC to DC` ... `when the system is in the sleep state`. What else do I need to say?

Comment: Here's one more example if my original question didn't make it. I have a laptop running on AC power. I then put it into sleep. Then someone unplugs the power. How do I get a notification of that event?

Comment: @c00000fd - Call GetSystemPowerStatus() when you get the resume notification.

Comment: @selbie: OK, but the resume notification may come in 2 hours or not come at all. I'm asking about the exact moment when the power source switches.